# Facebook page authentication. (not a user authentication)

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-page, facebook-authentication

I'm developing an application for companies that will automatically post data on their social media pages. However, I've got a big problem.

---

On Twitter, you only have one type of account, which is a user. So if a company registers for a Twitter account, it's still just a user. User authentication works like a charm, so no problems here.

---

Now, on Facebook, if a company registers an account, they can either make a user account, or a page account:

- A user account can have friends and post status updates(its just like your personal account)
- A page account can have **likes** and post updates(which is what i want companies to have)

User authentication is very simple, and works. But I cant find any information on page authentication (how to authorize an app to post updates for a Page profile). Is this not possible??? Think of the possibilities.

---

So, is it possible to authorize a Facebook app, to post updates on a page wall/account? (that is, instead of a user wall/account)

Thanks,
 
*Thomas*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/:

Page Login

You can impersonate pages administrated by your users by requesting the manage_pages permission.

Once a user has granted your application the "manage_pages" permission, the "accounts" connection will yield an access_token property for every page administrated by the current user. These access_tokens can be used to make calls on behalf of a page. The permissions granted by a user to your application will now also be applicable to their pages.

NOTE: After September 22, 2011, manage_pages permission will be required for all access to a user's pages via the /me/accounts connection, i.e. for both reading the user's pages and also retrieving access_tokens for those pages.

Cheers

Comment: Thank your very much, i seem to have missed it :)

Comment: When i go to the authentication url, and im logged in with the page account, an error occurs with no further information :(

Comment: It seems this only works on a user account that has a page, rather than a page account. well, guess that will be the requirement, Thanks  :>

Comment: Within facebook there are no page accounts... accounts are only for REAL people and REAL people manage Pages.. so all the calls for a page should be done from an account which manages a page...

Comment: this occurs when you make a page from the facebook home/register/login page. you get an account that is not capable of having friends or a profile picture and has its email adress as name. However, if you make a page when your logged in with a user profile, the administrator IS a user profile.